# CellDoubleClick vs CellMouseDoubleClick

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

`DataGridView` has two event handlers that appear similar: `CellDoubleClick` and `CellMouseDoubleClick`. What is the difference between these?

Comment: its basically celldoubleclick reffers to any button while cellmousedoubleclick reffers to any mousebutton.For example place a datgridview and subscribe to both events and inside each eventhandler place a messagebox with the name of the event it was fired then run and click a cell with left button(celldoubleclick will fire),and right button(cellmousedoubleclick will fire).If you have both and you interact with mouse then it will happen as i described.

Answer (score 2):

CellDoubleClick and CellClick are events that fire from the **left** mouse button, as well as "clicks" that come from tabbing to an item and hitting the spacebar, etc.

MouseDoubleClick and MouseClick are from mouse clicks of **any** button.

Also [Discussed on the MSDN Forums.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/35af1871-5898-4d19-b853-1e259a2b76fc/what-is-the-difference-between-celldoubleclick-and-cellmousedoubleclick)

Answer (score 0):

The CellDoubleClick event receives more information about the mouse. If the event handler needs information for example about the mouse position, use the CellMouseDoubleClick event.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx

The CellMouseDoubleClick-Event receives Click-Count, Location(Point,X,Y), MouseButton etc

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr
CellDoubleClick fires when ANY mouse button is double clicked. 
CellMouseDoubleClick fires only when the LEFT button is double clicked.

```
// Fires EVERY time ANY mouse button moves down
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine("MouseDown Event: " +  e.Button + " button." );
}


// Fires when the LEFT mouse button is double clicked
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine(" CellDoubleClick: LEFT Button was double clicked");
}



// Fires when ANY mouse button is double clicked
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine(" CellMouseDoubleClick Event: SOME Button was double clicked");
}
```

The results are:

```
// MouseDown Event: Left button.
// MouseDown Event: Left button.
//  CellDoubleClick: LEFT Button was double clicked
//  CellMouseDoubleClick Event: SOME Button was double clicked
//  
//  
// MouseDown Event: Middle button.
// MouseDown Event: Middle button.
//  CellMouseDoubleClick Event: SOME Button was double clicked
// 
//  
//  MouseDown Event: Right button.
// MouseDown Event: Right button.
//  CellMouseDoubleClick Event: SOME Button was double clicked
```